# Access to raw data in ARGB_8888 Android Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface, alpha-transparency, argb

I am trying to access the raw data of a Bitmap in ARGB_8888 format on Android, using the `copyPixelsToBuffer` and `copyPixelsFromBuffer` methods. However, invocation of those calls seems to always apply the alpha channel to the rgb channels. I need the raw data in a byte[] or similar (to pass through JNI; yes, I know about bitmap.h in Android 2.2, cannot use that).

Here is a sample:

```
    // Create 1x1 Bitmap with alpha channel, 8 bits per channel
    Bitmap one = Bitmap.createBitmap(1,1,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    one.setPixel(0,0,0xef234567);
    Log.v("?","hasAlpha() = "+Boolean.toString(one.hasAlpha()));
    Log.v("?","pixel before = "+Integer.toHexString(one.getPixel(0,0)));

    // Copy Bitmap to buffer
    byte[] store = new byte[4];
    ByteBuffer buffer  = ByteBuffer.wrap(store);
    one.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

    // Change value of the pixel
    int value=buffer.getInt(0);
    Log.v("?", "value before = "+Integer.toHexString(value));
    value = (value >> 8) | 0xffffff00;
    buffer.putInt(0, value);
    value=buffer.getInt(0);
    Log.v("?", "value after = "+Integer.toHexString(value));

    // Copy buffer back to Bitmap
    buffer.position(0);
    one.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
    Log.v("?","pixel after = "+Integer.toHexString(one.getPixel(0,0)));
```

The log then shows

```
hasAlpha() = true
pixel before = ef234567
value before = 214161ef
value after = ffffff61
pixel after = 619e9e9e
```

I understand that the order of the argb channels is different; that's fine. But I don't 
want the alpha channel to be applied upon every copy (which is what it seems to be doing).

Is this how `copyPixelsToBuffer` and `copyPixelsFromBuffer` are supposed to work? Is there *any* way to get the raw data in a byte[]?

**Added in response to answer below:**

Putting in `buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());` before the `copyPixelsToBuffer` does change the result, but still not in the way I want it:

```
pixel before = ef234567
value before = ef614121
value after = ffffff41
pixel after = ff41ffff
```

Seems to suffer from essentially the same problem (alpha being applied upon each `copyPixelsFrom/ToBuffer`).

Comment: Hi, I also encounter this problem. Have you found a way to solve this? Maybe the way to convert the data back to true RGB values?

Comment: You might want to check ``Bitmap.isPremultiplied()`` too. Guess it's set to ``true`` by default when alpha channel is present.

Comment: Have you tried `Bitmap.getPixels()`? The documentation explicitly says that it returns unpremultiplied ARGB pixels. There is also an answer about `getPixels()` below but you didn't comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is very stale and probably won't help you now, but I came across this recently in trying to get `copyPixelsFromBuffer` to work in my app.  (Thank you for asking this question, btw!  You saved me tons of time in debugging.)  I'm adding this answer in the hopes it helps others like me going forward...

Although I haven't used this yet to ensure that it works, it looks like that, as of API Level 19, we'll finally have a way to specify not to "apply the alpha" (a.k.a. premultiply) within `Bitmap`.  They're adding a [`setPremultiplied(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPremultiplied%28boolean%29) method that should help in situations like this going forward by allowing us to specify `false`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @KasperPeeters hehe, thanks!  I *hope* this solves our problems!

Answer (score 3):

One way to access data in Bitmap is to use getPixels() method. Below you can find an example I used to get grayscale image from argb data and then back from byte array to Bitmap (of course if you need rgb you reserve 3x bytes and save them all...):

```
/*Free to use licence by Sami Varjo (but nice if you retain this line)*/

public final class BitmapConverter {

    private BitmapConverter(){};

   /**
    * Get grayscale data from argb image to byte array
    */
   public static byte[] ARGB2Gray(Bitmap img)
   {

       int width = img.getWidth();
       int height = img.getHeight();

       int[] pixels = new int[height*width];
       byte grayIm[] = new byte[height*width];

       img.getPixels(pixels,0,width,0,0,width,height);

       int pixel=0;
       int count=width*height;

       while(count-->0){
           int inVal = pixels[pixel];

           //Get the pixel channel values from int 
           double r = (double)( (inVal & 0x00ff0000)>>16 );
           double g = (double)( (inVal & 0x0000ff00)>>8  );
           double b = (double)(  inVal & 0x000000ff)      ;

           grayIm[pixel++] = (byte)( 0.2989*r + 0.5870*g + 0.1140*b );
       }

       return grayIm;
   }

   /**
    * Create a gray scale bitmap from byte array
    */
   public static Bitmap gray2ARGB(byte[] data, int width, int height)
   {
       int count = height*width;
       int[] outPix = new int[count];
       int pixel=0;
       while(count-->0){
           int val = data[pixel] & 0xff; //convert byte to unsigned
           outPix[pixel++] = 0xff000000 | val << 16 | val << 8 | val ;
       }

       Bitmap out =  Bitmap.createBitmap(outPix,0,width,width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       return out;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this might have to do with the byte order of the ByteBuffer you are using. ByteBuffer uses big endian by default.
Set endianess on the buffer with

```
buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```

See if it helps.

Moreover, copyPixelsFromBuffer/copyPixelsToBuffer does not change the pixel data in any way. They are copied raw.

Comment: That changes the result, but not the main problem: the alpha channel is still being applied for every copy (see the added note in my question).

Comment: Indeed, copyPixelsToBuffer seems to be applying the alpha channel on to rgb channels. This can be seen clearly when you setPixel(0,0. 0x7f224466) - this will be 0x7f332211 when read into the buffer.
This might be a bug. Consider reporting this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but i got to the same issue, and just figured out that the bitmap byte are pre-multiplied, you can set the bitmap (as of API 19) to not pre-multiply the buffer, but in the API they make no guarantee.

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPremultiplied(boolean)):

> `public final void setPremultiplied(boolean premultiplied)`
>
> Sets whether the bitmap should treat its data as pre-multiplied.
>   Bitmaps are always treated as pre-multiplied by the view system and Canvas for performance reasons. Storing un-pre-multiplied data in a Bitmap (through `setPixel`, `setPixels`, or `BitmapFactory.Options.inPremultiplied`) can lead to incorrect blending if drawn by the framework.
>
> This method will not affect the behaviour of a bitmap without an alpha channel, or if `hasAlpha()` returns false.
>
> Calling `createBitmap` or `createScaledBitmap` with a source Bitmap whose colors are not pre-multiplied may result in a `RuntimeException`, since those functions require drawing the source, which is not supported for un-pre-multiplied Bitmaps.