# Get rgba uint8[] from ARGB_8888 bitmap

Tags: android, html, canvas, bitmap

I have a bitmap and I am trying to get the the data to be an rgba byte array. I can do `bmp.getPixels` but this is not in rgba bytes. My end destination was to feed this to an HTML5 canvas which requires an 4 elements (r, g, b, a) per pixel. Is this possible?

This is the code I am using to get my bmp:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
// can do bmp.getPixels here but it doesnt give RGBA :(
```

I tried this:

```
bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));
```

but the contents of buffer is extremely weird, it doesnt look like rgba to me, it looks like this:

```
[ 54, 59, 64, -1, 54, 59, 64, -1,
```

Those `-1`s especially look weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was already asked here, I believe it's a hint to yours.

[how to get RGB values of bitmap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669501/how-to-get-rgb-values-of-bitmap-in-android)

Comment: Thanks @scarto I updated my answer above to show you what I tried, things look just a little weird but I think I might have the data right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010545/access-to-raw-data-in-argb-8888-android-bitmap

Comment: Thanks scrato thats a very interesting topic!

Answer (score 2):

Each element of the pixel array is an int, containing argb values. You can get values like that:

```
int alpha = Color.alphpa(pixel);
int red = Color.red(pixel);
int green = Color.green(pixel);
int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon, so the way I tried with `copyPixelsToBuffer` is wrong?

Comment: `copyPixelsToBuffer` won't help you if you're just trying to get argb values from a bitmap

Answer (score 0):

So the RGBA bitwise manipulation out of pixel worked.

But `copyPixelsToBuffer` also worked, the only issue was I had to change the alpha from -1 to 255 and it matched the RGBA bitwise manip method too.

Thanks all for the help!